# Unix - Prevent files with specific name from being in a directory

Tags: linux, file-management, redhat-enterprise-linux

I need to prevent users from accidentally copy/move files with a certain names into a specific directory.  Is it possible ?

I need to set something in directory /home/similar2 that will reject any attempts to put files with names *mytimesheet.* into it. Files not matching these can be put in the directory.
Only need this for command line.

IBM Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL).  I'd love any generic Unix solution also.
Thanks. Binh

Comment: What names? What directory? Please give us an example to work with. What filesystem? What OS? Is this actually Unix (if so, which one?) or do you mean Linux (if so, which one?).

Comment: There are 2 kind of directories with similar names, say /home/similar1 and /home/similar2.  The users will periodically need to copy files, say such as mytimesheet.txt to /home/similar1.  I want to prevent them from accidentally put mytimesheet.txt to /home/similar2.  If I can also put up a warning, that would even be better.  IBM Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL).  Is there a generic Unix answer too ?

Comment: Linux is not Unix, they have very different tools despite their similarities. Even the different Linux distros have significant differences. I still don't understand, how is this hypothetical service going to guess whether a particular file should be allowed into `similar2` or not? Please [edit] your question and give examples of files that should be allowed and files that should not.

Comment: No guessing.  I need to set something in directory /home/similar2 that will reject any attempts to put files with names *mytimesheet*.* into it.

Comment: And it should allow other files to be written to it? Should this work on the command line, the GUI or both? If GUI, which one is used? Please [edit] your question and add all this extra information you have given in the comments. Comments can be deleted at any time and are harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an alias for the cp/mv commands in the user's .bashrc that checks where they're sending it before actually executing the command, and make their .bashrc immutable. You could also send a warning if its one of the files you don't want this way. This would prevent them from copying/moving files to that directory through a bash shell. Don't know if it would prevent them from copying/moving it in some other way, though; it depends if the other methods reference the active user's cp/mv commands. I don't know enough about all the ways to copy or move a file in Red Hat to know how much this would cover.

Comment: This could work.  I'll try to see if I can get this to work.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @Binh No problemo!

Comment: @Binh That doesn't prevent the user from unaliasing the commands again, so it's not a fool-proof solution.

Comment: @slhck Not even if .bashrc is immutable? I thought that would prevent unaliasing.

Answer (score 1):

You could run a `cron job`, say, every 5 minutes and check those directories. Any offending file would be promptly removed.

Works in all flavors of Unix.

A complete, foolproof solution requires modifying the kernel or at least the filesystem software.

In Windows this would be a lot easier, with `Watched Directories`.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to bounce back the command before it happens, because those files are important, I can't just delete them.  Thanks again.